# Running local gae server in port 80

Tags: linux, port, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine

I have an ubuntu 10.4 installation with apache2 running by default in port 80. I want gae to respond to that address instead of apache. I have changed the conf files for apache in order to use another port but still the 80 port gets bind to it. Despite if I stop apache /etc/init.d/apache2 stop still getting responses from the port. Am I missing something?

Comment: 'I have changed the conf files for apache in order to use another' Could you be more specific?

Comment: I have edited /etc/apache2/ports.conf and added the line Listen 8500 in and put in comments NameVirtualHost *:80

Comment: What about original line `Listen 80` ? Or have you just changed `Listen 80` to `Listen 8500` ? If you have no `Listen 80` in your `/etc/apache2/ports.conf` then some other app is listening on that port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find who use 80 port

```
netstat -anltp | grep \:80
```

Kill it:

```
kill `netstat -anltp | grep \:80 | sed -e 's/.*LISTEN[ ]*\([0-9]*\).*/\1/'`
```

Comment: bash: kill: 69.59.196.211:80: arguments must be process or job IDs, I get several errors like that. I don't like the idea of shutting down everything though :)

Comment: Find netstat -anltp | grep \:80, and kill PID

Comment: tcp 0    0 0.0.0.0:80     0.0.0.0:*  LISTEN      - 

I guess this is the one that I should kill but there is not pid only a dash. I want to bind my localhost address is this going to respond to 127.0.0.1?

Comment: Try: ss -anp | grep \:80

Answer (score 1):

Stop Apache if you still want it to run on 80:

```
sudo apache2ctl stop
```

Then run GAE as sudo using python 2.5:

```
cd <google_app_directory> 
sudo python2.5 dev_appserver.py -a 127.0.0.1 -p 80 /home/<your_username>/<app_directory>
```

This works great for me as i often use apache on 80 as well so i can switch between the two when required.